# What is the solution of $(4+t^2)\frac{dy}{dt}+2ty=4t$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

> \begin{align*}
> \newcommand{\dd}{\; \mathrm{d}}
> (4+t)^2\frac{\dd y}{\dd t} + 2ty &= 4t \tag{1}\\
> \implies (4+t^2)\frac{\dd y}{\dd t} + y\frac{\dd(4+t^2)}{\dd t} &= 4t \tag{2}\\
> \implies \frac{\dd}{\dd t}[(4+t^2)]y &= 4t \tag{3}\\
> \implies (4+t^2) y &= \int 4t \dd t\\
> \implies (4+t^2) y &= 2t^2 + C \\
> \implies  y &= \frac{2t^2 + C}{t^2+4}
> \end{align*}

I don't know how number 1 and number 2 are same...

Also, how number 2 and 3 are same... ?

Comment: Try going backwards and see if that enlightens.  Use product rule to go from 3 to 2 and take a derivative to go from 2 to 1.  Also, please use mathjax if you're going to post on this site.

Comment: You've here our [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write nice mathematics, also with the mouse right click Show Math As> Tex Commands you can explore formulas.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773). I hope the way I rewrote it is approximately what you wanted - feel free to edit it further.

Answer (score 7):

Why are one and two the same:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(4+t^2)=2t
$$
Why are two and three the same? The product rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}[(4+t^2)y]=(\frac{d}{dt}[4+t^2])y+(\frac{d}{dt}[y])(4+t^2)=2ty+\frac{dy}{dt}(4+t^2)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Work backwards:

$$\frac{d}{dt}[(4+t^2)y]=2ty+(4+t^2)\frac{dy}{dt}.$$

(You can fill the intermediate step.)